# Serialize to XML using boost::serialization

Tags: c++, xml, boost-serialization

This is a newbie question. I am trying to serialize some objects to XML, but the resulting XML contains a boost serialization signature, version information, class id, ...etc. that I do not need. Is there a way to get rid of them without post-processing the xml message?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/archive/xml_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/xml_oarchive.hpp>

using namespace std;

class Test {
private:    
    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template<class Archive> void serialize(Archive & ar,
            const unsigned int version) {
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(a);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(b);
        ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(c);
    }

    int a;
    int b;
    float c;
public:
    inline Test(int a, int b, float c) {
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
        this->c = c;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::ofstream ofs("filename.xml");

    Test* test = new Test(1, 2, 3.3);

    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(test);

    return 0;
}
```

results in:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
  <!DOCTYPE boost_serialization (View Source for full doctype...)> 
  <boost_serialization signature="serialization::archive" version="6">
  <test class_id="0" tracking_level="1" version="0" object_id="_0">
    <a>1</a> 
    <b>2</b> 
    <c>3.3</c> 
  </test>
  </boost_serialization>
```

I'll be serializing these messages to strings, though, and sending them to systems that expect a message to look like this.

```
  <test>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b> 
    <c>3.3</c> 
  </test>
```

Is there a way to serialize xml without the signature?

Answer (score 17):

the flag no_header eliminates the heading lines

```
unsigned int flags = boost::archive::no_header;
boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(ofs, flags);
```

the following macro eliminates the attributes

```
BOOST_CLASS_IMPLEMENTATION(Test, object_serializable)
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not what `boost::serialization` should be used for.  If you're looking to generate a specific type of XML, better use an XML generator like [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/) (yes, it says "parser" everywhere, but it'll also write XML).

Comment: Do you know of an example of using Xerces to generate the type of output @navigator wants?

Comment: Why do you say that's not the intended usage?

The docs [disagree with you](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html): «`This library will be useful in other contexts besides implementing persistence. The most obvious case is that of marshalling data for transmission to another system.`»

Comment: @FabioA. With that they probably mean, using boost serialize on both sides. In that case it is not persistence, but transmission; yet - the format is still boost serialization specific. I find it impossible to beat the format into the format that I need using boost serialization, so I think this is the correct answer.